# google maps error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, api, google-maps

Here is my function I created for gmaps

```
function createMap (qc,mess,ele){
        var myLatLng = qc;

          // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(ele), {
            center: myLatLng,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 4
          });

          // Create a marker and set its position.
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myLatLng,
            title: mess
          });
    }
```

Here is what my PHP generates from my Database

```
<div id="1_map"></div>
 <script>
 var qc_1 = {lat:44.6309454, lng:-123.0913114}; 
createMap(qc_1,"text Message", "#1_map");
</script>
```

Order of load is Google Maps API Call, javascript file with createMap, and then PHP generated Text.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById(ele)` doesn't need the hash symbol, I don't think.

try

`createMap(qc_1,"text Message", "1_map");`

not

`createMap(qc_1,"text Message", "#1_map");`